# Draw shifted plots from the same data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to draw a shifted plot from a data table (or a external file) without edit table coordinates. Using the `shift={(x,y)}` option works but `x` and `y` are not related to the axis coordinates `s` and `f`. Any advice?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    ymin=0, ymax=360,
    xlabel=$s$,
    ylabel=$f(s)$
]
\addplot[shift={(0.0,0.0)}] table[header=true,x=s,y=f] {
    s       f
    0.0     75.9638
    0.380665    75.9638
    0.380665    206.565
    0.58711     206.565
    0.58711     243.435
    0.793555    243.435
    0.793555    333.435
    1.0     333.435
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proper way to do achieve this is to use filters: You can use `x filter/.code={<code>}` to perform mathematical operations on the coordinates. Inside the `<code>` of an `x/y filter`, `\pgfmathresult` holds the current coordinate, and the content of `\pgfmathresult` at the end of the code will be used as the new coordinate. Alternatively, you can use the key `disabledatascaling` for the `axis` environment, then you'll be able to use the `shift` key in the way you tried it. This won't work with very large values that require the `fpu` library, however. The development version of PGFplots also supports using `shift={(axis cs:<x>,<y>)}`, which will work with large values.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    s       f
    0.0     75.9638
    0.380665    75.9638
    0.380665    206.565
    0.58711     206.565
    0.58711     243.435
    0.793555    243.435
    0.793555    333.435
    1.0     333.435
}\data

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    ymin=0, ymax=360,
    xlabel=$s$,
    ylabel=$f(s)$,
    no markers
]
\addplot table[x=s,y=f] \data;
\addplot +[shift={(-0.1,10)}] table \data;
\addplot +[x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+0.1}},
  y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-10}}] table \data;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: shifting plots in PGFplots]

Comment: The second `\addplot` doesn't work for me: `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x 
                                                 
l.28 \addplot +[shift={(axis cs:-0.1,10)}] t<<next line>>able \data;`

Comment: @Fernando: Sorry, this only works in the development version. You have to use the `disabledatascaling` key, or use the `x filter/.code`. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, third `\addplot` works great for me anyway.

Comment: @Fernando: Great! If you think this answers your question, it would be good if you accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it. That will mark the question as answered and give me and you some reputation.

Comment: I've used this answer a couple of days ago. However, I've since discovered that `shift={(...)}` also shifts the "sample curve" inside the legend, but only if there are multiple plots with different shifts. Also, at least in current pgfplots versions, you can use `x filter/.expression=x + 0.1`, which looks less TeXnical than the `/.code` version and is faster with luatex.